# manyToMany or oneToMany

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 Entites, `User` and `Orders`.

There are many users and many orders.

A user can have many orders.

In my Entities I have the following:

Orders.php

```
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="BM\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $user;
```

But looking at the db, this creates a user_id field that is unique, so I can't create anymore orders because the user_id is already in the db.

I know that this is wrong.

Do I need a `oneToMany` or `manyToMany` etc relationship so that I can have multiple orders per user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the following to `Orders.php`

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BM\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="orders")
 */
protected $user;
```

and then to `User.php`

```
/**
*
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BM\OrderBundle\Entity\Orders", mappedBy="user")
*/
protected $orders;
```

This has now fixed my issue